# React pagination component number of item displayed issue

Tags: reactjs

I simply don't know why I have 10 Items displayed instead of 8?
I'd like A hint as I'm not formidable on react.

On my demo I have 10 movies displaying on the page they should be 8. Not sure why the page PAGE_SIZE = 8 doesn't do the job.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance
[demo](https://codepen.io/gioexp/pen/KKqavNZ?editors=1010)

```
const PAGE_SIZE = 8;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell it seems the default page size for `https://www.omdbapi.com/` is 10 instead of 8, and I don't see any overt way to specify a page size to request. This is ***why*** you are rendering 10 results per "page".

What I suggest to do is to update your logic to fetch all the movies and handle the paging on the app side.

```
const getMovies = (term='marvel') => {
  setLoading(true);
  axios.get(`https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=cbb48c03&s=${encodeURIComponent(term)}&plot=full`)
    .then(response => {
    setMovies(response.data.Search);
  }).catch(error => {
    setMovies([]);
  }).finally(() => setLoading(false));
}
```

Use the current page number and `PAGE_SIZE` to slice up the current page to render.

```
const genCards = () => {
  const allCards = [];
  if (movies) {
    movies.slice(pageNo * PAGE_SIZE, pageNo * PAGE_SIZE + PAGE_SIZE)
      .map(movie => {
        allCards.push(<Card {...movie} cardClicked={handleCardClicked} />);
      });
  }
  return allCards;
}

const allCards = genCards();
```

The `total` is derived state from the `movies` array length, so it shouldn't be stored in state. The initial `pageNo` should also be `0`.

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
const [showPop, setShowPop] = useState(false);
const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
const [movie, setMovie] = useState({});
const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState('marvel');
const [pages, setPages] = useState(1);
const [pageNo, setPageNo] = useState(0);

const maxPages = Math.floor(movies.length / PAGE_SIZE);
```

The next/previous page handlers should account for page numbers starting at `0`.

```
const onNext = () => pageNo < maxPages && setPageNo(pageNo + 1);
const onPrev = () => pageNo > 0 && setPageNo(pageNo - 1);
```

And the same for the page count and current page, and button disabling:

```
<span>{movies.length} results found</span>
...
Page {pageNo + 1} of {maxPages + 1}
...

<button onClick={onPrev} className="pagination-button" disabled={pageNo === 0}>
  &lt;
</button>
...
<button onClick={onNext} className="pagination-button" disabled={pageNo === maxPages}>
  &gt;
</button>
...
```

#### Update

> I've noticed that the search now is broken something from const
> maxPages.

I incorrectly used the length of the `movies` array which only accounts for what you've already fetched and not the total aggregate movie count. For this we will save the `totalResults` value from the response into local state.

```
const [totalResults, setTotalResults] = useState(0);

const maxPages = Math.floor(totalResults / PAGE_SIZE);

const getMovies = (term = "marvel", page = 1) => {
  ...
  axios
    .get(....)
    .then((response) => {
      ...
      setTotalResults(response.data.totalResults);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      ...
    })
    .finally(() => setLoading(false));
};
```

> also the search is not showing less results

The issue here is the API returns a message that there are too many matches, so it's not returning a Search array and the UI falls over when attempting to access the length property.

I just added a check for this error response and throw an error so the `.catch` can handle it.

```
const getMovies = (term = "marvel", page = 1) => {
  ...
  axios
    .get(....)
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.data.Error) throw new Error(response.data.Error);

      ...
      setTotalResults(response.data.totalResults);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // handle error here
    })
    .finally(() => setLoading(false));
};
```

I noticed also that this API returns only 10 results no matter what, so requesting per page is still required. To resolve this I worked out a relationship between paging by 8's and paging by 10's.

```
const PAGE_SIZE = 8;
// API page size is 10, we display 8 per page
const PAGE_SIZE_TO_PAGE_REQUEST_RATIO = 4 / 5; // 8:10 == 4:5

const getApiRequestPage = (page) =>
  Math.ceil(page * PAGE_SIZE_TO_PAGE_REQUEST_RATIO) + 1;
```

| pageNo | page by 8's | results by 8's | page by 10's | results by 10's |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 8 | 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 2 | 16 | 2 | 20 |
| 2 | 3 | 24 | 3 | 30 |
| 3 | 4 | 32 | 4 | 40 |
| 4 | 5 | 40 | 5 | 50 |
| 5 | 6 | 48 | 5 | 50 |
| 6 | 7 | 56 | 6 | 60 |
| 7 | 8 | 64 | 7 | 70 |
| 8 | 9 | 72 | 8 | 80 |
| 9 | 10 | 80 | 9 | 90 |
| 10 | 11 | 88 | 9 | 90 |
| 11 | 12 | 96 | 10 | 100 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Use a React ref to store the maximum page fetched from the API and only fetch the next page when `pageNo` has been incremented higher.

```
const maxPageFetched = useRef(-1);

useEffect(() => {
  const nextPage = getApiRequestPage(pageNo);
  if (nextPage > maxPageFetched.current) {
    getMovies(keyword, nextPage);
  }
}, [keyword, pageNo]);
```

When the search param changes then assume this begins a new series of fetches and paging, reset the state.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setMovies([]);
  setPageNo(0);
  setTotalResults(0);
  maxPageFetched.current = -1;
}, [keyword]);
```

The final issue to resolve had to do with the slicing and mapping of the `movies` array. The `imdbID` property seemed like a great candidate for use as a React key, but for some reason the API you are using doesn't filter very well and returns duplicate data. The absolutely correct solution is to file a bug with the repo. The slightly less correct solution is to filter out these duplicate entries in the front end, accounting for new total results length, etc... The quick & dirty solution is to simply generate your own unique GUIDs for each movie element fetched.

```
import { v4 as uuidV4 } from "uuid";

...

const getMovies = (term = "marvel", page = 1) => {
  setLoading(true);
  axios
    .get(
      `https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=cbb48c03&s=${encodeURIComponent(
        term
      )}&plot=full&page=${page}` // <-- fetch by page
    )
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.data.Error) throw new Error(response.data.Error);

      maxPageFetched.current = page; // <-- update last page fetched
      setMovies((movies) =>
        movies.concat( // <-- concat the next page
          response.data.Search.map((movie) => ({
            id: uuidV4(), // <-- map page results and add id property
            ...movie
          }))
        )
      );
      setTotalResults(response.data.totalResults);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // error
    })
    .finally(() => setLoading(false));
};

...

const allCards = movies
  .slice(pageNo * PAGE_SIZE, pageNo * PAGE_SIZE + PAGE_SIZE)
  .map((movie) => (
    <Card
      key={movie.id} // <-- use id as React key
      {...movie}
      cardClicked={handleCardClicked}
    />
  ));
```

[image: Edit react-pagination-component-number-of-item-displayed-issue]

Comment: @user173420 Sure. What is the issue?

Comment: if you check the pagination is wrong now, it shows Page 2 of 1

Comment: @user173420 Oh, I see, sorry about that. It should be `Page {pageNo + 1} of {maxPages + 1}` instead of `Page {pageNo + 1} of {maxPages}`... just add 1 to the `maxPages` value.

Comment: I've noticed that the search now is broken something from const maxPages. https://codepen.io/davide77/pen/dyRvvWB?editors=0010 could you please help? also the search is not showing less results:-(

Comment: @user173420 Yeah, I've a fix for the search, the issue there is the API returns a message that there are too many matches, so it's not returning a `Search` array and the UI falls over when attempting to access the `length` property. I noticed also that this API returns only 10 results no matter what, so requesting per page is still required. I'm working on a solution that handles the difference between paging by 8's converted to API's paging by 10's.

Comment: @user173420 Ok, I think I've resolved the issues you mention plus the ones I found. Please take a look and reconsider.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't put page size into query params so response has default 10 items. That is reason why there are 10 item that displayed See image below [image]

In your API documents, they don't support page size
[image]